# Получение строки из файла и перевод её в тип int Python

Tags: python

Функция читает логин пользователя из файла users.txt (там всегда только один логин), после чего ищет такой же в progress.txt, если находит то необходимо заменить следующую после логина строчку на единицу больше, из 1 сделать 2, из 2 из и т.д. - это обозначение номера занятия. Если логин введён впервые то просто записать его в progress а за ним 1. 
Проблема в том, что я не понимаю как достать эту строку с цифрой из файла,перевести её в int, прибавить 1, и записать на то же место. Может ответ очевиден, но я всего несколько дней знаком с Python и многого еще не понимаю. Заранее спасибо

```
with open('users.txt', 'r') as f:
line = f.readline()
f.close()
with open('progress.txt', 'r') as k:
while True:
    global uroka_in
    lines = k.readline()
    if line == lines.rstrip():
        uroka_in = int(k.readline().rstrip())
        urokb_in = uroka_in + 1
        uroka_str = str(uroka_in)
        urokb_str = str(urokb_in)
        lines.replace(uroka_str, urokb_str)
        k.close()
        break
    if not lines:
        k.close()
        global urokb_in
        urokb_in = 1
        with open('progress.txt', 'a') as j:
            j.write(line)
            j.write('\n')
            j.write(str(urokb_in))
            j.write('\n')
            j.close()
            break
```

Пример файла progress.txt:

```
username1
1
username2
1
username3
1
```

Правка:

```
def user():
with open('users.txt') as k:
    user = k.readline()
    k.close()
def increment_counter(user, 'progress.txt'):
    with open('progress.txt', 'r') as f:
     data = yaml.safe_load(f.read())
    data[user] += 1
    with open('progress.txt', 'w') as f:
    yaml.dump(data, f, indent=2, default_flow_style=False)
```

Comment: Текстовые файлы, пожалуй, один из худших и неудобных вариантов (форматов) хранения в вашем случае. Я бы на вашем месте хранил данные (`progress.txt`) в виде YAML, INI или XML файла. Первые два формата легко читаются (т.е. являются user friendly)

Comment: Неужели нет возможности использовать txt

Comment: конечно есть, но это очень громоздко и неэффективно

Comment: не подскажите как , может ссылки или ещё что-то @MaxU

Comment: вы можете привести пример файла `progress.txt`?

Comment: user1 \n 1 \n user2\n 1 записано построчно

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
import json

def progress():
    #p_dict = eval(open('progress.txt').read())
    p_dict = json.load(open('progress.txt'))
    user = next(filter(bool, map(str.strip, open('users.txt'))))

    if user in p_dict:
        p_dict[user] += 1
    else:
        p_dict[user] = 1

    with open('progress.txt', 'w') as f:
        json.dump(p_dict, f, indent=0, sort_keys=True)
```

пример 'progress.txt'

```
{
"user0": 1,
"user1": 4,
"user3": 2
}
```

пустой 'progress.txt' изначально должен содержать одну строку: `{}`

Еще вариант, как хочет автор вопроса:

```
def progress():
    iter_lines = filter(bool, map(str.strip, open('progress.txt')))
    p_dict = {k: int(v) for k, v in zip(iter_lines, iter_lines)}
    user = next(filter(bool, map(str.strip, open('users.txt'))))

    if user in p_dict:
        p_dict[user] += 1
    else:
        p_dict[user] = 1

    with open('progress.txt', 'w') as f:
        f.write('\n'.join('{}\n{}'.format(k, p_dict[k]) for k in p_dict))

    return user, p_dict
```

пример 'progress.txt'

```
user0
1
user1
4
user3
2
```

Comment: SyntaxError: unexpected EOF while parsing

Comment: пустой 'progress.txt' изначально должен содержать одну строку: `{}`

Comment: запись может иметь только такой вид? @vadimvaduxa

Comment: что конкретно вы имеете в виду, вопрос не ясен

Comment: Уже разобрался, спасибо большое

Comment: добавил вариант, progress.txt такойже как у вас

Comment: не используйте eval() в случаях когда json.loads() достаточно.

Answer (score 1):

Попробуйте так:

```
import yaml   #  требует установленного модуля `yaml`: pip install pyyaml

def get_user(filename=r'/path/to/users.txt'):
    with open(filename) as f:
        return f.readline()

def increment_counter(user, filename):
    with open(filename, 'r') as f:
        data = yaml.safe_load(f.read())
    data[user] += 1
    with open(filename, 'w') as f:
        yaml.dump(data, f, indent=2, default_flow_style=False)
```

Пример использования:

```
increment_counter(get_user(r'/path/to/users.txt'), r'/path/to/progress.yml')
```

Пример YAML файла (`progress.yml`) до вызова функции:

```
username1: 1
username2: 1
username3: 1
```

Содержимое `"progress.yml"` после вызова `increment_counter('username3', r'/path/to/progress.yml')`:

```
username1: 1
username2: 1
username3: 2
```

---

Функция для обычного текстового файла (как в вопросе)

```
def increment_counter(user, filename):
    with open(filename, 'r') as f:
        data = f.read()
    with open(filename, 'w') as f:
        pat = r'(' + user + r'[\r\n]+)(\d+)'
        m = re.search(pat, data)
        if m:
            s = m.group(1)
            s += str(int(m.group(2)) + 1)
            new = re.sub(pat, s, data)
            f.write(new)
        else:
            f.write(data)
```

Пример использования:

```
increment_counter('username3', r'/path/to/progress.txt')
```

PS рекомендую использовать YAML для хранения данных о пользователях

Comment: что за аргумент функции user, что в него записать?

Comment: @андрейгривкин, добавил пример использования в ответ...

Comment: Сори за нубский вопрос но, что надо писать вместо filename @MaxU

Comment: @андрейгривкин, полный путь к файлу

Comment: progress.txt??? @MaxU

Comment: SyntaxError: invalid syntax

Comment: @андрейгривкин, в какой строке ?

Comment: Правка в вопросе, я понимаю. что дичайше туплю, простите

Comment: @андрейгривкин, получилось?

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/71316/discussion-between---and-maxu).